# What is the first letter in the first name and in the surname in Cyrillic?

Tags: выбор-имени, буквы

[image]

What is the equivalent letters in the Latin alphabet and what is the first letter in the first first and in the surname in Cyrillic?

Comment: The first word is most probably not a surname, but "явился" - "(he) appeard". The whole would be "Yan appeared".

Comment: The letter Y - ī Graeca in Latin alphabet. But today "J" is very often used. cf. John, Jean, etc.

Answer (score 13):

As [Alissa](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/1836/alissa) correctly said, the first letter in both words is `Я`, and the first name is `Янъ` (Yan). But the first word is "Явился". It is neither a first name nor a surname, it means "[there] came". The image is most likely a scan or a photo from a parish book in which the newborn children were recordered. Every such record begins with the name of the place and date. Then it's usually written, "**There came** {person's name and surname}, aged X, {profession}, and in the presence of {names of 2 witnesses} presented a newborn child, born on {date} from {mother's name}". The child was baptized and given the name {name}, god-parents being {names and surnames of a man and a woman}. This Act was signed by {the name of the parish administrator}. {the name and the signature of the priest who wrote this record}."

What I mean is your image has only the first name, the surname must follow the frirst name, that is, it is written to the right of the first name `Янъ`, and it is not in your image.

Once I translated such a record into English, on Linguistics StackExchange, [have a look](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like first letter of name and surname is "Я". There is no equivalent letter in Latin alphabet. It's usually transliterated as "Ya"

Name is most certainly Янъ (it's pre-reform spelling, would be Ян today). It's Russian version of name Jan.

Surname is more difficult. Looks like Яв...я What's in the middle I'm unsure.